# How to enable submit button after filling up all fields in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I want to do is, after filling up all fields it should enabled the button. 
But if there's a empty field it should disabled.

for example
[image]

if the field is remarks (required) the button automatically disabled but if the field is remarks (optional) it will enabled

example:

passed - passed = enable button
passed - failed = disable button it should fill up it first before it will enabled
failed - failed = disable button fill up all fields.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-xz4c93?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use FormArray instead of normal array

Comment: @MustafaKunwa how?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mustafakunwa/reactive-form-in-angular-with-formarray-2595e5ee1d31

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button"
      [disabled]="taskFormGroup.invalid"
      [nzLoading]="formLoading" (click)="saveFormData()">
```

As long as your empty fields have Validators.required specified, `[disabled]="taskFormGroup.invalid"` should be all you need. The form group `valid` state depends on the **Validators** that you specify.

Comment: What if the field is optional? it should automatically enabled

Comment: If you have an optional field, do not add a Validators.required to its FormControl.

Comment: after fillup the first item. it automatically enabled

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-xz4c93?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html if its correct